# Data integrity after GPT restore on Mdraid configured disk

Tags: mdadm, gpt

I've restored backup GPT headers on previously GPT partitioned disks that are member of a Linux software raid (mdraid). This was done because partprobe reported corrupted headers.

Now actually software raid should manage the entire disks but the previously used partition information remains from the time when the server was used in a different fashion.

Realizing that GPT is probably not relevant in my setup I removed GPT information entirely through gdisk expert mode.

My worry at this point is however that my fiddling around with GPT table restore/GPT information removal might have corrupted my software raid.

The system itself doesn't show any signs that this is the case (still boots, data is accessible) but I wondered if someone can advise if the data could still be corrupted by my actions or what way I could check the integrity of the data.

Comment: Which version superblocks are you using? Either `mdadm -D /dev/mdX` or `mdadm -E /dev/sda` will tell you (in the "version") field.

Comment: The superblock version is 1.2  
`md1 : active raid6 sdag[5] sdh[2] sdab[6] sdx[7] sdp[1] sdt[4] sdl[0]
      19534435840 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [7/7] [UUUUUUU]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.2 metadata is stored 4K from the start of the block device. The data itself is a fair bit in, typically. For example, here is (part of) `mdadm -E` from a disk in one of my arrays:

```
/dev/sda3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
⋮
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=2224 sectors
⋮
```

As you can see, 8 sectors in (8 * 512 bytes/logical sector = 4KiB) is the array superblock. The data is much further in, 128MiB in fact.

GPT layout is the first sector (#0) is a protective MBR; the next 33 sectors (#1–#33) the GPT partition table and entries. The last 33 sectors on the disk store the backup.

So, restoring from the backup GPT partition table may overwrite the first 34 sectors total. But it wouldn't touch the data (because that's well over two hundred thousand sectors away). Depending on how much space is unused after, then even writing to the backup at the end wouldn't cause corruption (there is plenty in my array, yours may differ.)

It sounds like your superblocks were not destroyed, though, as you have assembled the array since. I'd confirm by checking `mdadm -E` on each disk, but other than that, it sounds like no harm was done. You may also want to clear and re-enable the write-intent bitmap if (a) in use and (b) internal, as that's stored in the space between the superblock and the data.